# No data returned using Axios Post with Parameter Object

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, vue.js, axios

I am having problems using Axios and making a post with a parameters object to a Laravel route.

If I use a query parameters `e.g. ?username=user` the post request works. But if I use an object it fails:

---

Here is the Axios post request:

```
let params =
{
    'username': 'help',
    'password': 'me'
};
axios.post(
'https://cors.now.sh/https://jumprope.design/test-login', params, {
headers: {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'accept-language': 'en_US',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    '_token': 'UawpqT74cr9sr0Uut0lttZPE2YKDb1ckvXYpzNJW'
}
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

When I remove the params obj and append `?username=user` to the URL route, it works and I am returned data from the request.

---

Here is the Laravel (5.1) Controller:

```
protected function postTestRequest(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request::all();
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

---

Hitting this route in the browser or testing using postman works fine: [https://cors.now.sh/https://jumprope.design/test-login](https://codepen.io/jumprope-design/pen/yzYgaz?editors=1012)

Here is a link to the codepen as well: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/jumprope-design/pen/yzYgaz?editors=1012)

Thanks very much for any help or guidance.

---

Also, I have tried the advice here https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format but still received the same results.

Comment: If the code works when you pass the variables as `GET` variables and not as `POST` variables than your server-side code is what you should be looking at.

Comment: How did you connect router to the function?

Comment: @Dekel Everything works fine if I return a json response from the controller and use axios to `GET` the response.

Comment: @Roozbehhz here is what the routes look like in routes.php `Route::get('test-login', 'AdminController@postTestLogin');
Route::post('test-login', 'AdminController@postTestLogin');` I have tried using a different method for returning the view also (e.g. `AdminController@getTestLogin`, but no luck

Comment: Is there anything prined in the console?

Comment: @JoeAllen, how your reply is relevant to what I wrote?

Comment: @Dekel Sorry, I meant if I change the route to use `GET` and send data back in a json response it works. You're asking if I hit that post route with the same parameters does it return data? Yes. It's because I have both a GET and POST route pointing to the same controller method. If I separate the methods, one method to return the view/handle the get route and the other method to handle the post route, then NO, nothing is returned when I use parameters. I think it has something to do with the axios / JS code. Testing the link in the browser and using Postman both return the desired  result.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your routes file and see if the route you want to target is defined with 'POST' method since you are hitting with 'POST' and check that 
 the route is targeting to 'postTestRequest' method. There is definitely something wrong with your routes. Also check to see if any other route is not conflicting with it.

Comment: The routes.php file definitely uses `POST` method for the `postTestRequest` function. I have also disabled the CSFR token check and  have added an exception for this route in the VerifyCsrfToken.php middleware file.